# What's the difference between Yii 2 advanced application and basic?

Tags: yii2

What is the difference between advanced application and basic application in the Yii framework?

Does they have any differences regarding security?

Comment: The advanced template requires the following commands be run after installing.
yii init
yii migrate
Maybe someone can answer in terms of those commands.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The following table shows the similarities and differences between the basic and advanced templates:

[image: Comparison]

Source: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/start-comparison.md

As you can see, the main differences are:

- Advanced template supports front- and back-end apps;
- Advanced template is ready to use User model;
- Advanced template supports user signup and password restore.

Answer (score 21):

There is no difference as the underlying core framework code is the same.

The difference is the structure of the project - the *most obvious difference* is that advanced one already has a "backend" set-up for you, which you can see for yourself:

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced

Comment: how can I start working with advanced? I mean, i can't find index.php as in basic.

Comment: @Ricardo you need to init the app, in terminal type `php init` while you are in your project root, it it will generate and built you missing files.

Comment: links are dead now :(

Answer (score 20):

There is no much different. 
but you already have administration panel(**backend**) in Yii 2 advanced application template.

backend and frontend work as separate application while using common models and configuration. you can create your own number of apps under root folder.

lets say you want to create RESTFull API in same project. simply you can create another directory call 'api' same as backend or frontend, and it'll contain folder structure same as backend except assets, views, widgets etc.

you have to decide structure of your project based on requirement.

[Setup RESTful API in Yii2(budiirawan)](https://github.com/deerawan/yii2-advanced-api)

Answer (score 13):

One of the main differences (other than the folder structure to handle the fontend/backend thing) is that the advanced template has a working user authentication system, whereas the basic has the users hardcoded in the user model.  The Advanced template has working SignUp/Forgot Password functionality.

Answer (score 11):

There is no difference in the core framework, the difference between the templates is the folder structure, you have the `backend`, `frontend` and the `common`.

Usually I use the `backend` to make the admin area, and the `frontend` to make the user area, but if need you can create another directory to make an api as [Chanuka Asanka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26240434/4423322) already said. The `common`configs will be merged with the `backend` and `frontend` config files.

The advanced template as some features like signup, password reset and User model ready to use, besides that you dont have any difference, the core still the same so don't have any security difference.